# LazyGit: Can anyone show a real example of the pull-request config for Azure DevOps?

Tags: git

If I want to create a pull-request from LazyGit, I need to setup a provider in the `config.yml`. The syntax shown in the documentation is like this:

```
services:
  '<gitDomain>': '<provider>:<webDomain>'
```

But there is no actual examples of how what each field should contain - except `<provider>`.

Has anyone successfully set this up for Azure DevOps? And if so how should the line be made?

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I've tried `"gitcompanyname.visualstudio.com": "azuredevops:dev.azure.com"` but I get the error message "Failed to parse repo information from url"

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is the exact same thing that I tried. I kind of gave up, since it wasn't really more than just a nuisance for me, I might pick it up again later, if I get annoyed enough. :-) If I figure it out, I'll be sure to write it here as an answer, and request an update of LazyGit's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set up the pull request config for Azure DevOps with the following configuration:

```
  services:
    "dev.azure.com": "azuredevops:dev.azure.com/companyname"
```

You can find the full documentation here:
https://github.com/jesseduffield/lazygit/blob/master/docs/Config.md#custom-pull-request-urls

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).